# How & where to use setInitialSavedState & saveFragmentInstanceState inside Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a `Fragment` that retains its state after it is shown back.

For this I tried using `getFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState()` inside `onPause()` & then calling `setInitialSavedState()` inside `onCreateView()`.

Issues I'm facing is I dont know how to use them exactly and when to call them.

Also both functions take a paramater of type `SavedState`, which I'm not sure how to use.

**Code:**

```
public class AudioContainerFragmentClass extends Fragment implements
        OnClickListener {

    final String TAG = "AudioContainerFragmentClass";
    private Button bSetName;
    private TextView tvName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView()");
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_fragment_container, null);
            bSetName = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bSetName);
            tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            bSetName.setOnClickListener(this);

            if(savedInstanceState != null){
                setInitialSavedState(/* WHICH SavedState OBJECT TO PASS */);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate()");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView(): " + e.toString());
        }
        return view;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState()");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tvName.setText("sometext");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState( /* WHAT TO ADD HERE */);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just investigating this myself and thought I'd record what I found.

`setInitialSavedState()` can't be called after a `Fragment` has been attached to an `Activity`, as noted in the Android source code [around line 491](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-mr1-dev/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java).

`setInitialSavedState()` is intended to be used immediately after instantiating fragments in code. For example:

```
AudioContainerFragmentClass newFrag = new AudioContainerFragmentClass();
newFrag.setInitialSavedstate(savedStateObject);
```